# Hybris : language model not found

Tags: java, internationalization, sap-commerce-cloud

Let's assume we create a new `languageModel` in hybris `vi_VN`, using this impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Language; isocode[unique = true]; name[lang = en]; fallbacklanguages (isocode); active[default = true];
                      ; vi_VN                 ;  Vietnam       ; en                         ;                       ;
```

When the user selects the `vi_VN` language from the website, we use `commonI18NService` to get the current locale:

```
final Locale locale = commonI18NService.getLocaleForLanguage(language); // language isocode is "vi_VN"
```

So when the language is `vi_VN` (isocode = `vi_VN`"), the following line `locale.getLanguage()` returns `vi` and not `vi_VN`

My question is when creating a new composed `languageModel` like **xx_XX** should we also create the `languageModel` **xx**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vi_VN` has two parts: the first part is the language code and the second part is the country code.

In order to get the country code, you need to use [`CommonI18NService#getCountry`](https://help.sap.com/doc/a4265d5ea8314eb2929e6cf6fb8e35a5/1811/en-US/de/hybris/platform/servicelayer/i18n/CommonI18NService.html#getCountry-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Yes, but it's not the name of the country that I need, I am wondering why `locale.getlanguage()` returns `vi` instead of `vi_VN`, since locale is created from a language with isocode `vi_VN`

Comment: I think it's like you said because it takes the first part before "_" as the language

Comment: Yes. Did you check what it is returning for `en_US`? I will need to initialize my system in order to confirm it.

Comment: Same thing it returns `en` for `en_US`

Comment: Exactly. So, you need to use `CommonI18NService#getCountry` to get the country code.